# Git Merge per commit?

Tags: git, git-merge

So here is the thing, I recently got accepted in a job, now, I was looking into how they created their branches, now I came across this issue where their DIP branch (development in progress) is behind by 51 commits from the master, and 145 commits ahead of the master, so sure thing, I just merged everything, but then there were so many conflicts that it warrants me to just abandon the merge and look at the commit logs, here is the problem, when I started comparing the 51 behind commits I realized that there were so many commits in between commits that were added to master but not in dip, I am confused how to merge this easily. I think what happened, is that, the past developer, committed fixes on the release branch and master branch, but didn't commit to dip branch, and then committed again fixes on release branch and master branch, and dip branch, and so fort, instead of merging, master with dip branch... So now, is there a way to merge this one by one.

Is there a way to merge by commits?

Comment: Back up.  It sounds like you have a Git mess which may have been caused by a combination of a lesser understanding of Git, and an acute lack of understanding of their workflow.  The real questions here are, why did you merge this branch without really talking to anyone else on the team (more hypothetical than anything), and what state do you want the repository to be in when you're done?  As an additional thing, do you know the *exact* commit SHA of the merge that you did?

Comment: Oh I forgot to say, After git merge, there were so many conflicts, that it warrants me to just abandon the merge, and look at the files, and that is where I saw that there were so many commits that are in-between commits, its not me...

Comment: Right.  This is where it'd be a really good idea to talk to your lead about this.  We can't really help you fix all of the conflicts (and getting out of that state is simple enough), but you can at least start a dialog.

Comment: well the past dev already resigned... so this mess has been pushed on to my shoulders...

Comment: In general, don't do huge merges straight away. Do a 'trial merge' first: create a new branch `git checkout -b dip-merge-test dip` and try to merge _that_ into `master`. If successful, you can `git checkout dip; git reset --hard master` to make `dip` and `master` identical; if not, you can just throw away the `dip-merge-test` branch and try again.

Comment: I did a lot of trial merge, but the conflicts are insane, so to gain my sanity, I did the cherry-picking from the very first commit, and fixed the conflicts each time, atleast for every commit i only see 1 or 2 conflicts, and not see, like 50+ conflicts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the rebase function, as explained [in the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Or create a new branch and use `git cherry-pick` with each commit.

Comment: I ended up creating a new branch and cherry-picking each commit... but this is better than fixing all those conflicts...

Comment: This is terrible advice but... whatever works I guess. Now you're just hiding conflicts